# How to arrange Bootstrap grid with one column vertically centered next to a 4x4 grid?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am still learning how to use Bootstrap, and I was wondering how you can arrange the grid more freely.
I am trying to have a single div centered vertically on the left, and a 4x4 grid on the right. I've provided an example image of how I want to arrange my divs in the format I want. Please see the
[Example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTkxG.gif)

How would you accomplish something like this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would use grid system instead of bootstrap in this case. Something like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="grid-container">
        <div class="child a">Image</div>
        <div class="child b">Text 1</div>
        <div class="child c">Text 2</div>
        <div class="child d">Text 3</div>
        <div class="child e">Text 4</div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.grid-container {
            display: grid;
            height: 50vh;
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: coral;
            border: 1px solid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
            grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
            grid-row-gap: 20px;
            grid-column-gap: 20px;
        }
        .child {
            background-color: cornflowerblue;
            border: 1px solid;
        }
        .a {
            grid-area: 1/1/3/3;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

With bootstrap I recommend you to use flex properties

### Example

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-around p-3 bg-dark" style="height: 350px; width: 350px">
  <div class="bg-light" style="height: 100px; width: 100px">IMAGE</div>
  <div class="row bg-light p-1" style="height: 150px; width: 150px">
    <div class="col-6 bg-secondary text-light">1</div>
    <div class="col-6 bg-secondary text-light">2</div>
    <div class="col-6 bg-secondary text-light">3</div>
    <div class="col-6 bg-secondary text-light">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

- d-flex: display flex
- align-items-center: this centers all your items vertically
- align-content-around: is how items are spaced horizontally, around takes the free space and as you can see distributes it equally